# iPhone Crashes After UIImagePickerController Finishes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using the iPhone camera to capture an image and them resizing and adding a rounded corner.  I'm having some users complain about crashes and I can't seem to find the problem.  Also, the code runs very slow after selecting an image.

Can anyone offer suggestions to improve the method below?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(500, 500);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *picAsPNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

    self.imageView.image = newImage;

    self.passedItem.itemImage = picAsPNG;
    self.eraseButton.hidden = NO;
    self.scrollImageButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem right there. Are there crash reports available in iTunes Connect so you can pinpoint the problem down to the type of crash and perhaps the line in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a memory problem? I kwow UIImagePicker often causes memory warnings on older devices: are you releasing anything upon memory warning that you're assuming will be there later?

Comment: That was mostly it, I think.  I got ride of the resizing code and I can't get it to crash.  I think I was just using too much memory.